# Forcing web app to run in 32-bit from web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, oledb

Im trying to connect to an access database from a ASP.NET aspx page (C#) but am recieving the error:

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

After some research I suspect it is because the server is 64bit, and the Jet driver that interacts with the access db is not supported for 64-bit. Previous solutions suggest either forcing the web app to run in 32-bit mode instead of "any cpu", or upgrading to an illusive 64bit version of the driver on the server. The problem is I do not have direct admin access to the server, only folder access to edit files (including web.config). So my question is.. is it possible to force the script to run in 32-bit mode from a setting in the web.config / aspx file only? (ie. No server/IIS changes) Otherwise ill have to battle a bureaucracy to get the changes made to the server ;-)

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the [enable32BitAppOnWin64](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults) attribute on applicationPoolDefaults:

> Optional Boolean attribute.
>
> When true, enables a 32-bit application to run on a computer that runs
>   a 64-bit version of Windows.
>
> The default value is false.

```
<applicationPools>
   <add name="DefaultAppPool" />
   <applicationPoolDefaults enable32BitAppOnWin64="True">
   </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>
```

I will admit I have never tried it myself, but it should work.

Comment: Unless im putting it in the wrong place, this doesnt seem to be setable from web.config =( Gives me an internal server error.

Comment: Verified it, will not work. That is a global level IIS setting.

Comment: Thanks for checking nunespascal. Apprechiate your time. Perhaps its not possible.. I will start poking admins with sticks.